# How to save mails in Unix?

Tags: email, command, mail-command

I wanted to save mail in unix in some directory, as we do in outlook (files are saved with .msg extensions). Is there any workaround for doing this.

Comment: Mail is a vast subject - you need to explain what your current configuration is.  What is your mail client etc?

Comment: Mails usually saved in your user mail box after you have read it. The user mail box is normally located in their $HOME directory.

Comment: Unix doesn't do mail, just like your shoes don't dance. How do you access your email, when you are not on Windows?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can use `save` command:

```
save [msglist] /YourDir/file
```

this command will append messages to file.

or you can use `pine`: (http://www.washington.edu/pine/tutorial.4/index.html#SavingMsg)

To save a message to your saved-messages folder:

At the Message Index screen, use the arrow keys to highlight the message you want to  save, or, at the Message Text screen as you view a message, press S (Save). You are asked if you want to save the message to the saved-messages folder or to another folder:

```
SAVE to folder in <Mail...> [saved-messages]:

Press <Return> to choose the default folder: [saved-messages]. Pine saves your message, and you see the following:

[Message # copied to "saved-messages" in <Mail...> and deleted]
```

Comment: Sadly the link has expired.